# Keras model predicting the same values from canvas image (Image Recognition)

Tags: reactjs, tensorflow, keras, canvas, tensorflow.js

I'm very new to machine learning and I trained a simple Keras neural network to identify handwritten digits using the MNIST dataset.

Here is what the model looks like:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28)),
    keras.layers.Dense(100,activation="relu"),
    keras.layers.Dense(10,activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

model.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs=8)
```

Now I made a React Application where a user draws on a canvas and presses a submit button where the model then makes a prediction. I imported my model using Tensorflow.js and when the model makes a prediction, no matter what I draw on the canvas, it outputs the same result.

Here is the App.js:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react'
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';

async function generatePrediction(image) {
  let prediction = 0;
  const model = await tf.loadLayersModel('/model.json');
  let step1 = tf.browser.fromPixels(image)
    .resizeNearestNeighbor([28, 28]).mean(2).toFloat().expandDims(0).div(255.0)

  prediction = model.predict(step1);
  let digits = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
  prediction.data()
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      let max_val = -1
      let max_val_index = -1
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        if (data[i] > max_val) {
          max_val = data[i]
          max_val_index = i
        }
      }
      var result = digits[max_val_index];
      console.log(result);
    })
}

const Canvas = props => {
  const canvasRef = useRef(null)
  var image = new Image();
  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
    ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    //Our first draw

    let isDrawing = false; //Check if drawing

    //If drawing then make a line from the beginning to the mouse.
    const drawing = (e) => {
      if (!isDrawing) {
        return;
      }

      ctx.lineTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.lineWidth = 10;
    }

    //Mouse down start draw
    const startDraw = () => {
      isDrawing = true;
      ctx.beginPath();
    }

    //Set drawing back to false when done drawing
    const stopDraw = () => {
      isDrawing = false;
    }
    ///Mouse Event listeners
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", drawing);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", stopDraw);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", startDraw);

    setInterval(function () {
      image.src = canvas.toDataURL()
    }, 100);
  }, [])

  function makePrediction() {
    generatePrediction(image);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <canvas id="myCanvas" width="280" height="280" ref={canvasRef} {...props} />
      <h1> The Guessed Number Is: </h1>
      <button onClick={makePrediction}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Canvas
```

And this is the result:
[Prediction Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKcPo.png)

Even if I redraw a new number and press submit to predict, it shows the same values.

[Prediction values exactly the same given a new number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRioX.png)

Is there any reason why this happens?

I suspect it's the image I pass in and if it's formatted correctly.

Comment: could you share the trained model evaluation metrics?

Comment: If the test image happens to be loaded from normalized train_images , you may get this error because images in there are already normalized need not require normalizing again before predicting. 
You can refer to this [StackExchange thread](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/32353/getting-same-result-for-all-predictions-in-cnn) where the same issue has been resolved.